# Is it possible to create a 2-part web to lead form with download links?

Tags: salesforce1-platform, form

Is it possible to create a 2-part web to lead form in Salesforce with these features?

1. Create a page where the user can select a checkbox next to the documents that they want to download. There will be 3-4 options.
2. After they select the checkboxes, it will take them to a form where they fill in their name, email and other contact information.
3. After they submit the form, it will redirect them to a thank you page where they can download the requested files.

Comment: yes it is possible. what issue you are seeing in this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think standard web to lead functionality could handle the 2nd step. It will take the given form values and submit them to Salesforce. After that it will redirect the user to the thank you page.

However, the other two parts are outside the standard functionality. You could certainly make a web page for the first step of the process that uses API calls into Salesforce to get the list of documents for the user to select. Then pass those options over the the web-to-lead form for submission to Salesforce.

For the thank you page, you could encode the selected documents into the `retUrl`. Then when they land on that page dynamically update the content so they can download the documents. Alternatively, you could email them the links from Salesforce when the lead is created.

With the level of API interaction required for the 1st and 3rd steps you might want to skip web-to-lead altogether. If you are already making API calls to get the document details, why not just do the lead creation with an API call as well.